# New FormData is returning empty object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have issue that Ajax request to server and I want to get my all form data and submit it to server. Problem is when I using `new FormData(form)` is returning an empty object. I done this work before my previous projects and it worked fine. But why not working this time?. I know about `.serializeArray` but I don't want to use this because of some reasons. The reason is I want to add some files and want to push it to the server.

```
jquery-version: 3.4.0
```

Form:

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="email" name="username"/>
    <input type="password" name="password"/>

    <button type="button" id="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('#btn').on('click', function () {
         let formData = new FormData($('#myForm')[0]);
         console.log(formData);
     });
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is entries in your for data object but you are printing formdata object in console. try following to print entries.

**You need to iterate loop of entries of formdata to print.**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#btn').on('click', function () {
    let formData = new FormData($('#myForm')[0]);
    for(var item of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(item[0]+ ', '+ item[1]); 
    }
  });
})
```

So, if you find entries. so you would need to serialize it to pass it into ajax. or you can create object by entries and pass it using `JSON.stringify(data)`

```
var formObject = {};
formData.forEach(function(value, key){
    formObject [key] = value;
});
```

//In AJAX

```
data: JSON.stringify(formObject);
```

And you can get using "POST" or your particular method into server